# Print hosting default URL (or channel URL) with Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase-cli

The Firebase CLI tool can show me the default URLs of the hosting site(s) of a project in a human-readable format:

```
$ firebase hosting:sites:list

Sites for project <my-app>

┌──────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ Site ID          │ Default URL                      │ App ID (if set) │
├──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ my-app           │ https://<my-app>.web.app         │ --              │
└──────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

If I have multiple channels, it can also show me the URLs for each channel on a given site:

```
$ firebase hosting:channel:list

Channels for site <my-app>

┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Channel ID │ Last Release Time   │ URL                              │ Expire Time │
├────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ live       │ 2022-10-27 15:06:54 │ https://<my-app>.web.app         │ never       │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

But how do I print *only* the URL of a channel, for use in a shell script? (Without resorting to regexes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `--json` argument.

Combined with jq, you can retrieve a specific URL.

Example with live channel:

```
$ firebase hosting:channel:list --json |\
jq '.result.channels[]|select(.name|contains("live")) | .url'
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any command that prints just the default URLs. The CLI uses a package `cli-table` and prints all the data together.

You can however use the [Firebase Hosting REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/projects.sites) to list all the sites of a project and their channels and create a script or even better fork the [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) and add a new function alongside [`listSites()`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/src/hosting/api.ts#L481) function of the CLI to print the URLs without the table.

The REST APIs response is just an array of sites so it should be pretty straightforward:

```json
{
  "sites": [
    {
      "name": "projects/<project_id>/sites/<site_id>",
      "defaultUrl": "https://<project_id>.web.app",
      "type": "DEFAULT_SITE"
    }
  ]
}
```